# How to check value is empty, or null in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem when I wanna get data from state, in console.log appears 2 values. I want remove the empty value, but I've run out of ways. How to remove an empty value?

[image: 1]

```
class DetailOrderTracking extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        const { query } = this.props.router;
        var getOrderTrackings = await OrderTrackingRepository.getOrderTracking(query.numberbill, query.courier);
        if (getOrderTrackings.ordertracking.status.code == 200) {
            var getManifest = getOrderTrackings.ordertracking.result.manifest;
            this.setState({ data: getManifest });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        console.log(data) // will print 2 values, first condition is empty value, and second condition has values (an example is in the image above)
        return (
            <div/>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: check the `length` of the `data` array --> `data.length`. If its zero, array is empty.

Comment: What does that mean, you "want to remove the empty value"? Your component starts out with empty data, and `render` is called. Then you populate the data, and `render` is called again at that point…

Comment: so if length>0 render.....

Comment: If you are using lodash, you have a method called isEmpty to check or the best way to determine whether the array is empty or not is by the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        if (data.length > 0){
          console.log(data)
        }
        return (
            <div/>
        )
    }
```